How to count the number of cells in a range that has been named with the Dim statement in VBA
I am trying to figure out how to use things like .count with a range that I have stored as a variable in VBA
I have made the following function which works
Function test2() As Variant

    test2 = Sheet12.Range("B1:B19").Count
    
End Function

This returns a value of 19 as there are 19 rows in that range.
When I do the following it just returns "#VALUE!" despite being the same other than how the range is stored
Function test2() As Variant

    Dim Grada As Variant
    Grada = Sheet12.Range("B1:B19")

    test2 = Grada.Count
    
End Function

Is VBA unable to use statements like .count on ranges once they have been stored in this way or what am I missing?

Grada is a Variant, not an Object, and so, without the use of the keyword Set will be treated as a Value. The other subtle issue here is the use of default methods/properties.
Sheet12.Range("B1:B19") has a hidden default member that returns the values, so in your second code you returned an array (a 2-D array at that) of Variants that reflect the content of those 19 cells. An array is not an Object, so does not have methods. The important thing to note here that the use of the hidden default member means that you are not returning a Range as you had assumed.
Set Grada = Sheet12.Range("B1:B19") may have had the desired result, but such late binding means that you cannot use IntelliText/AutoComplete to assist you in determining what methods and properties are available.
The other option here is to understand that a two-dimensional array is generated, and generalising that any block of cells can be selected:
Function test2() As Variant

    Dim Grada As Variant
    Grada = Sheet12.Range("B1:B19").Value2 'I have added this last bit to make the default member explicit

    test2 = (UBound(Grada,1) - LBound(Grada,1) + 1) * (UBound(Grada,2) - LBound(Grada,2) + 1)

End Function

I leave it as an exercise for the OP (a simple exercise at that) to determine why that formula works. The use of UBound and LBound removes any vagaries on 0-based or 1-based arrays - it is something that I now do as a habit so that my code is inherently safer if I copy bits to somewhere else.

I understand bits and pieces of what you're saying here.
Trying to understand your code with some success.
'(UBound(Grada,1) This should get me 19 as that is the upper bound of my array - LBound(Grada,1) + 1) This should be a 2? as the lower bound is 1 (UBound(Grada,2) No clue what is happening here as the array only has one entry?? can't find any explanation on what the second variable is referring to with my current level of understanding of VBA - LBound(Grada,2) + 1)' as for why these are being subtracted from each other and then multiplied I am utterly lost

No, Grada being a Variant is not what determines the type of assignment and the use, or lack of the use, of the default properties. It's the presence of Set.

@GSerg- Thank you amended for completeness, noting Balaz's answer.

@IzakNash: Understanding arrays ( how to count and what the bounds are) is an important fundamental skill., but beyond the scope of this question and answer. There are plenty of tutorials and articles on-line that will explain this, with examples.
